# R SVM algorithm

Tags: r

Can someone please explain this line of code, on from what svm, `., data, Kernal, and ranges??

```
tune.out <- tune(svm,
                 mpglevel ~ .,
                 data = Auto,
                 kernel = "linear",
                 ranges = list(cost = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000)))
```

Comment: `?tune` provides details on the arguments. `mpglevel ~ .` is the formula notation to create a model with `mpglevel` as the outcome variable and all other variables in the `Auto` dataframe as predictors.

Answer (score 0):

```
tune.out <- tune(svm,
             mpglevel ~ .,
             data = Auto,
             kernel = "linear",
             ranges = list(cost = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000)))
```

"svm" => the support vector classifier


"mpgelevel ~. " => classify the dependent variable mpglevel over the rest independent variables of the dataset


"data = Auto" => the variable that holds the data set


"kernel = 'linear'," =>The function of kernel is to take data as input and transform it into the required form. Different SVM algorithms use different types of kernel functions. These functions can be different types. For example linear, nonlinear, polynomial, radial basis function (RBF), and sigmoid.  

The basic kernel "linear" means you believe that there is a straight line which separates your dataset into 2 classes. If a straight line cannot split your dataset, then you need to transform the data into different dimensions, for example this dataset, will not have a straight line to split it into 2 classes.

[image]

That is when you chose other kernels. The kernel functions are explained, for example, [here](https://data-flair.training/blogs/svm-kernel-functions)

"ranges = list(cost = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000)))" => is different values of "cost of classification" you want to measure the svm against. or how much an SVM should be allowed to “bend” with the data. For a low cost, you aim for a smooth decision surface and for a higher cost.